# HTML5 date type required, not validating properly, when using oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Customtext')". How to solve this?

Tags: html, validation, date, tooltip

I have a Html5 input date field that validates properly if it is not filled. It displays a default message `"Please fill out this field"`

But if I want to display a custom message the validation still trowing an error, even if the field was filled.
Check tihs [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6pg1z6c/2/).

If I delete `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Put here custom message')"` the input element works good

This is the code:

```
<form action="action_page.php">

   <input id='dt_DueDt' class='required' name='nm_DueDt' type='date' required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Put here custom message');" >
   <input id="btnNext" class='btn_submit' type="submit" name="submitNext" value="Next">

</form>
```

Checking the MDN I could not find a solution. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API's_element.setCustomValidity()).
Any idea in what is breaking the validation process?

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have change the approach. Now I am using `https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/` and using bootstrap tooltip `http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips` to display the message.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've found an answer to this problem but still not a solution.

As stated at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

> Constraint API's element.setCustomValidity()
>
> The element.setCustomValidity(error) method is used to set a custom
>   error message to be displayed when a form is submitted. The method
>   works by taking a string parameter error. If error is a non-empty
>   string, the method assumes validation was unsuccessful and displays
>   error as an error message. If error is an empty string, the element is
>   considered validated and resets the error message.

So, this method has to be used to display a custom message from within the validation logic.